# Пузырьковая сортировка двумерного массива

Tags: python, пузырьковая-сортировка

Есть задача написать пузырьковую сортировку для входных данных. Не могу найти ошибку, не получается отсортировать данные в двумерном массиве по числу.

Входные данные:

```
3
Petrov Petr 3 3 3
Dzeranov Iosif 5 5 5
Guev Timur 5 5 5
```

Выходные данные:

```
Dzeranov Iosif
Guev Timur
Petrov Petr
```

Функция `array_to` преобразует строку в двумерный массив, где находятся имя,  фамилия (первый элемент) и число - именно по нему необходимо отсортировать массив.

Я набросал такой код:

```
def array_to(n, arr):
    from statistics import mean
    d = list()
    for i in range(n):
        d.append([' '.join(arr[i][0:2]),
                mean([int(i) for i in arr[i][2:5]])])
    return d
    
def bubble_sort(array):
    for i in range(len(array) - 1, 0, -1): 
        for j in range(i):
            first = array[j][1]
            second = array[j+1][1]
            if first > second:
                temp = array[j]
                array[j] = array[j + 1]
                array[j + 1] = temp
    return array

n = int(input())
times = n
stud = list()
while n != 0:
    stud.append(input().split())
    n -= 1
#array_to_dict(times, stud)
print(bubble_sort(array_to(times, stud)))
```

Если кто поможет, буду благодарен!

Comment: Какая ошибка? Что не работает? Вроде все норм. Или вы хотите сортировать по убыванию (не возрастанию)?

Comment: Не знаю, магия. Скопировал текст с сайта. Заработало...